# How can I resolve React Hook error when I'm not in month view?

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I start to use ReactBigCalendar but when I want to switch to Agenda/Week/Day view I have an error even if I start with other view then Month I have an error

This is my code :

```
const localizer = ReactBigCalendar.dayjsLocalizer(dayjs)

const PlanningPage = () => {

    return <React.Fragment>
        <Calendar
            localizer={localizer}
            views={['day','month']}
            defaultView="month"
        />
    </React.Fragment>
}
```

i have the cdn of dayjs, react-big-calendar.

How can I resolve my issue ?